# Product Variant Name using GraphQL in Bigcommerce

Tags: graphql, bigcommerce, graphql-js, gql, bigcommerce-stencil-cli

I'm using GQL query to show product variant information inside my table but when I'm calling product name its not working. Even my SKU,UPC/MPN and all rest values are showing but don't know how to show product name.
This is my site theme table [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4M6hk.png) And this is my dashboard [Dashboard Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QLeP.png)
This is my GQL query through which I'm taking variant information [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0heO.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variants are associated with options that do have names. We gather the names for all options and concatenate them together to get the variant's name. e.g. "Large Red".

Here's the variant part of the graphql we use to get that information:

```
variants(first:50 entityIds:[1,2,3]){
    edges{
        node{
            options(first:50){
                edges{
                    node{
                        displayName values(first:50){
                            edges{
                                node{
                                    label
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, Yes its working in query. But I'm calling it wrong inside  view file using handlebars.

` {{#each gql.data.site.product.variants.edges}}
        {{#each options.edges}}
            {{#each node.displayName.edges}}
                {{node.label}}
            {{/each}}   
        {{/each}}
     {{/each}}`

Comment: I get to the data using JavaScript. I guess you will have to test your handlebars until you get it right.

Comment: May I have your JavaScript code or any hint please.

Comment: My code is too integrated to share. Basically, a JSON object is returned and you need to traverse it to get to your data. A good start would be to output the response to the console so you know the structure. I traverse to the options displayName to get the options name and then concatinate all the options labels yo get its value.

Answer (score 0):

Variants do not have their own names (they only have a SKU code), so you can simply re-use the product's name. You can add the `name` field to your query underneath the `product` node, on the same level as `variants`.

Comment: Hey
Yes, I followed your answer but still couldn't get the products variant name in my theme front. 
Here's my code through which I'm calling it inside from product underneath fields: 
` {{gql.data.site.product.name}}`